# Match rows with other row with smallest difference on a column

Tags: r, matching

I want to perform matching between two groups in a data frame, where all rows belonging to one group (binary) are matched with observations from the other group (with replacement) if their difference on another column is smaller than a pre-set threshold. Let's use the toy-dataset below:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10),
                 group = rbinom(10,1, 0.3),
                 value = round(runif(10),2))

threshold <- round(sd(df$value),2)
```

Which looks like this

```
> df
   id group value
1   1     0  0.96
2   2     1  0.45
3   3     0  0.68
4   4     1  0.57
5   5     1  0.10
6   6     0  0.90
7   7     0  0.25
8   8     1  0.04
9   9     0  0.33
10 10     0  0.95

> threshold 
[1] 0.35
```

In this case, I want to match rows with `group==1` with rows with `group==2` where the difference between `value` is smaller than  `threshold`(0.35). This should lead to a data frame looking like this (apologizes for potential error, did it manually).

```
   id matched_id
1   2          3
2   2          7
3   2          9
4   4          3
5   4          6
6   4          7
7   4          9
8   5          7
9   5          9
10  8          7
11  8          9
```

Thank you!

Comment: What was your matching function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

***UPDATED ANSWER:* Was going slow on a larger dataset, so I tried to make the code a bit more efficient.**

Came up with a solution that seems to do what I want. Not sure how efficient this code is on larger data but seems to work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# All values
dist_mat <- df$value

# Adding identifier
names(dist_mat) <- df$id

# Dropping combinations that are not of interest
dist_mat_col <-dist_mat[df$group == 0]
dist_mat_row <- dist_mat[df$group == 1]

# Difference between each value
dist_mat <- abs(outer(dist_mat_row, dist_mat_col, "-"))

# Identifying matches that fulfills the criteria
dist_mat <- dist_mat <= threshold 

# From matrix to a long dataframe
dist_mat <- melt(dist_mat)

# Tidying up the dataframe and dropping unneccecary columns and rows. 
dist_mat <- dist_mat %>%
  rename(id = Var1,
         matched_id = Var2,
         cond = value) %>%
  filter(cond == TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "id") %>%
  select(id, matched_id)
```

This leads to the following dataframe:

```
> arrange(dist_mat, id)
   id matched_id
1   2          3
2   2          7
3   2          9
4   4          3
5   4          6
6   4          7
7   4          9
8   5          7
9   5          9
10  8          7
11  8          9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df |> left_join(df, by = character())` which is the tidyverse way of performing a cartesian product. Then filter according to `threshold`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  left_join(df, by = character()) |>
  filter(group.x != group.y,
         id.x < id.y,
         abs(value.x - value.y) < threshold)

#>+    id.x group.x value.x id.y group.y value.y
#>1     2       1    0.45    3       0    0.68
#>2     2       1    0.45    7       0    0.25
#>3     2       1    0.45    9       0    0.33
#>4     3       0    0.68    4       1    0.57
#>5     4       1    0.57    6       0    0.90
#>6     4       1    0.57    7       0    0.25
#>7     4       1    0.57    9       0    0.33
#>8     5       1    0.10    7       0    0.25
#>9     5       1    0.10    9       0    0.33
#>10    7       0    0.25    8       1    0.04
#>11    8       1    0.04    9       0    0.33
```

Comment: I used your solution for a vector with 10 million elements, and then your solution is having problems. Do you have any suggestions on how to make your solution more feasible for large datasets?